# How to get url of the caller page that initiated the ajax call

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

My web service wants to know what is the page url of the caller.

I checked the HttpReq -> Url it is the actual web service Url. Also the HttpReq -> UrlReferrer but it is not right, neither.

Is it possible to find out the caller page url from server side at all? Or do I have to pass in the url via service dto?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What's wrong with referer (UrlReferrer)? That's the normal (but unreliable) way to do it. Why do you need to know what it is?

Comment: @spender my caller page is localhost/page1.cshtml, UrlReferrer at this time gives me localhost/, and Url gives localhost/api/call. But i want to see localhost/page1 as my correct answer.

Comment: So the AJAX call happens on a page where the address bar says `http://localhost/page1.cshtml` but UrlReferrer on the server says `http://localhost/`?

Comment: @spender, yes. because UrlReferrer actually remembers the startup page when i first landed the localhost/, then from there i click a link and go to localhost/page1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the page URL as a parameter to your web service by using the JavaScript `document.location.href` notation, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourPage.aspx/DoSomething",
    data: "{'pageUrl' : window.location.href}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

Then you can handle the `pageUrl` value in your service code.

Comment: @ karl& spender, so pass in url via dto seems to be the way. I just thought maybe we could detect it from server side, as js could be modified and not 100% trustworthy. Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If, for whatever reason, UrlReferrer doesn't work out for you then... the page where the request came from knows what its address is, right? Why not supply this data to the javascript that served the Ajax request, so you can send it up with the Ajax request?